# Weird request handling in laravel right after making changes to code

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a laravel app with livewire. I have both `npm run dev` and `php artisan serve` running.

When I make a change to my code and try, for instance, to click on a link. The page fully reloads very quickly, clicking again does what's expected and subsequent requests in the app are handled fine until I make a change again.

Network request made when clicking a link after making a change in the code: [image: Description is the sentence before this]

Clicking the link again makes this normal looking request [image]

Comment: Please add more details. Do you see anything in the logs? Can you spot any remarkable differences in the request- or response-headers between both attempts?

Comment: I've added network tab request info, there is nothing remarkable where the artisan command runs @dbrumann

Comment: it says 'switching protocols'. Are you doing anything weird with http and https? Maybe in vite? Maybe in the `APP_URL` in your `.env` file?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary, I'll add the livewire tag as this may be a livewire-related thing